# I am expecting to see data in Kibana when I test an API on WSO2, but the indices are empty and I can't access any historical data

Tags: wso2, kibana, elastic-stack, wso2-api-manager, elk

I have set up an ELK with WSO2 following the official documentation and configuring everything required. Elasticsearch, Kibana, Logstash, Filebeat, and the API Manager are all running correctly. However, when I test an API on WSO2, Kibana shows no data in the indices and I can't access any historical data. What could be causing this issue?
(wso2am-4.1.0 ,logstash-8.6.2,kibana-8.6.2,elasticsearch-8.6.1)

When I test an API on WSO2, I expect to see data.

Comment: Do you see any errors?